# Missing Library

Tags: development, vala

I'm trying to get into developing for Elementary using Vala. I have been unsuccessfully trying to build Valama (an IDE for Vala) for ages but keep hitting hurdles.

Currently when I try to make Valama (having satisfied all dependencies) I get the following error:

`error: Package 'webkit2gtk-3.0' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories`

I have `apt-get install`'d both `webkit2gtk-3.0` and `webkit2gtk-3.0-dev` but the error persists. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of errors I always search in the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/valama-git/) for missing dependencies, when I install all the dependencies the problem, most of times fixes, if not you should read the oficial git/webpage because maybe it can have bugs. So check out if you have installed this packages:

- `clutter-gtk`
- `gdk-pixbuf2`
- `gdl`
- `glade`
- `glib2`
- `gtksourceview3`
- `intltool`
- `libgee`
- `webkit2gtk`
- `cmake`
- `imagemagick`
- `vala-0.26`

I hope this information will help you, for me worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is coming from the Vala compiler and suggests the VAPI file is not being found for webkit2gtk-3.0. It looks likes Valama fixed this by adding `webkit2gtk-3.0.vapi` to its repository with this commit:

[CMake: Add webkit2gtk-3.0 vapi to support vala < 0.26](https://github.com/Valama/valama/commit/6a77fadea92eec8b14c5041b091c126d6d3d30a9)

Maybe that helps you a little. I tried building Valama on Fedora 23, but CMake reports:

`--   Package 'webkit2gtk-3.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:360 (message):
  A required package was not found`

This is to do with the pkg-config file `webkit2gtk-3.0.pc` not being found. I didn't try any futher to repeat the error message you are getting.